# Linking with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions. In routes.rb they look like this.

```
resources :posts do
 resources :comments do
 end
end

resources :comments do
 resources :questions do
 end
end
```

I am trying to link to the comment_questions path from a _post partial (being called in the posts index view) with the following:

```
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(post, comment) %>
```

It links to the comment_questions path but goes to a question belonging to the wrong comment.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing in the comment and question object to comment_question_path(comment, question) if you are linking to the show action of QuestionsController

The url generated for comment_question_path will be

```
GET comments/:comment_id/questions/:id  questions#show
```

With what you are doing, `comment_questions_path(post, comment)`, it will use post id for comment and comment id for question and you will go to a totally different page

Comment: and another thing is that it should be `comment_question_path` path without `s`

Comment: This gives me a 'no route matches missing required keys: [:comment_id]' error.